# HelpPage for ASP.NET vNext MVC 6 Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently checking out asp.net vnext MVC6 in Visual Studio 2015 Preview. I'm pretty new to asp.net in general, but within my company we are going to move towards creating a web api using asp.net for accessing data on our server (currently we only support wcf communication with our own silverlight application). This is the reason I am checking out the new functionalities of MVC 6 to judge whether we should wait before starting our development and use MVC 6 when it is finally released or start development now and create a Web API 2 project.

Anyway, I am looking into auto documenting the web api, which is already integrated into the Visual Studio template for a WebApi 2 project by use of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage.

Now for my question, is something like this available for MVC 6 aswell? I can import the same package in my project.json in my ASP.NET vNext / MVC6 (whatever you want to call it) project but i can't do `app.UseHelpPage();` in my Startup.cs file.

I suspect this is not (yet) integrated in the current release yet. If not, is there anything known about integration of this feature once ASP.NET vNext eventually hits the shelves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this feature is not available in MVC 6 yet, but you could try Swagger. 
Swagger basically is a framework for describing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful APIs.
The nice thing about Swashbuckle that it has no dependency on ASP.NET MVC, so there is no need to include any MVC Nuget packages in order to enable API documentation, as well Swashbuckle contains an embedded version of swagger-ui which will automatically serve up once Swashbuckle is installed.

Source: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will  keep this in mind! As it stands now though, it also doesn't work with MVC 6. I think this has to do because and MVC 6 project is a .kproj instead of a .csproj, the nuget package for Swashbuckle gives an error when installed.

Comment: There is a way to get this working in ASP.NET v6: http://devmeetsbi.ghost.io/help-and-test-page-for-asp-net-web-api-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/

Comment: If your API is not restful, then this is not working well, though. I would not say this is a valid answer as it only partially will help you. When you use custom commands or model/action binding, or if you're creating not a REST but a more RPC-like based API this won't work as Swagger is very opinionated.